# Working with "multiple" select

Tags: php, html

In my profile advanced search i have an mutiple select type..

```
<form method="POST">
                     <select size="6" name="Cities" multiple="multiple" id="Cities">
    <option value="0">All</option>
    <option value="1">City1</option>
    <option value="2">city2</option>
    <option value="3">city3</option>
    <option value="4">city4</option>
    <option value="5">city5</option>
</select>
</form>
```

How do I use it, I mean how should i call what they have chosed...As you can choose one or more options (by holding in control, or just holding in mouseclick and point to other options).

Answer (score 4):

Give it the name `Cities[]` instead of `Cities`, and you'll have an array in `$_POST['Cities']` on submit.

Answer (score 2):

google helps
http://www.onlinetools.org/tricks/using_multiple_select.php

Comment: This link is no longer functional